# Google Sheets: cell value based on another cell's multiple possible values (list from a range data validated)

Tags: validation, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Simple task: Cell A32 is a data validated to "List from a range" cell. In other words it's a drop-down list cell with several pre-filled values (say, Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta). I want Cell B32 to check Cell A32 and return "$" value if A32 is only Alpha or Delta (here I'd like to be able to add as many conditions as I need, say return "$" if A32 is Alpha, Delta, Omega and etc.). If A32 is something else or blank - no value should be returned. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A32; "(?i)Alpha|Delta|Omega"); "$"; )
```